# opencv - How can I create a big image from several small ones?

Tags: opencv

I'm new to opencv.
My question is as following:
I have a big image. I'd like to take its 4 corners, in such a way so that  from each of the corners take a 5X5 pixels region. Then I'd like to create one big image based on the 4 corners.

The new image will be of 10X10 dimensions.

What would be the best way to get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Are python answers ok for you?

Comment: i'm working in ios, but I can adapt some python code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple function to create an image by combining the 4 corners of an image in OpenCV C interface. I don't know if it is the best way or not, but it works:

```
IplImage* getCorners(IplImage* img, int regionWidth, int regionHeight)
{
    IplImage* result = cvCreateImage(cvSize(regionWidth * 2,regionHeight * 2),img->depth,img->nChannels);

    //Copy Top Left Region
    cvSetImageROI(img,cvRect(0,0,regionWidth,regionHeight));
    cvSetImageROI(result,cvRect(0,0,regionWidth,regionHeight));
    cvCopy(img,result);

    //Copy Top Right Region
    cvSetImageROI(img,cvRect(img->width - regionWidth - 1,0,regionWidth,regionHeight));
    cvSetImageROI(result,cvRect(regionWidth,0,regionWidth,regionHeight));
    cvCopy(img,result);

    //Copy Bottom Left Region
    cvSetImageROI(img,cvRect(0,img->height - regionHeight - 1,regionWidth,regionHeight));
    cvSetImageROI(result,cvRect(0,regionHeight,regionWidth,regionHeight));
    cvCopy(img,result);

    //Copy Bottom Right Region
    cvSetImageROI(img,cvRect(img->width - regionWidth - 1,img->height - regionHeight - 1,regionWidth,regionHeight));
    cvSetImageROI(result,cvRect(regionWidth,regionHeight,regionWidth,regionHeight));
    cvCopy(img,result);

    //Reset Image Region Of Interest
    cvResetImageROI(img);
    cvResetImageROI(result);

    return result;
}
```

I hope it helps. :)

Comment: fantastic thanks! Don't you need to free any memory here though?

Comment: No, the function is creating an image internally. You need to free the returned image from where you will call this function.

Answer (score 4):

With the C++-Interface, you can do it like this:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
cv::Mat CornersOnly(const cv::Mat& src, int cw, int ch)
{
    using namespace cv;
    int w(src.cols);
    int h(src.rows);
    CV_Assert(w >= cw);
    CV_Assert(h >= ch);
    Mat dst(2*ch, 2*cw, src.type());
    Mat(src, Rect(0,    0,    cw, ch)).copyTo(Mat(dst, Rect( 0,  0, cw, ch)));
    Mat(src, Rect(w-cw, 0,    cw, ch)).copyTo(Mat(dst, Rect(cw,  0, cw, ch)));
    Mat(src, Rect(0,    h-ch, cw, ch)).copyTo(Mat(dst, Rect( 0, ch, cw, ch)));
    Mat(src, Rect(w-cw, h-ch, cw, ch)).copyTo(Mat(dst, Rect(cw, ch, cw, ch)));
    return dst;
}
int main()
{
    cv::imwrite("Lenna_Corners.png", CornersOnly(cv::imread("Lenna.png"), 100, 100));
}
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

For better visibility I used 100 instead of 5 Pixels in this example.